# Output image src with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, image, simplexml

I'm trying to output an image with SimpleXML, but the image tag doesn't appear in the source code.

Can anyone help me outpout this image:

Here's my [XML](http://events-prod.stanford.edu/xml/byCategory/0/mobile.xml) and code:

```
        <?php foreach($xml->Event as $event) { ?>
        <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $event->link; ?>">
                <?php if ($event->Media['url'] == !null) { ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $event->Media['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $event->title;?> thumbnail" />
                <?php } ?>
                <h3><?php echo $event->title; ?></h3>
                <p><strong><?php echo $event->beginDate; ?> at <?php echo $event->beginTime; ?></strong></p>
                <p><?php echo $event->location; ?></p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: The XML you pointed to is an HTML page for me. Can you paste it inline with just a few Event elements?

Comment: @onteria Sorry, my XML link was wrong. It has been updated.

Comment: @Danzan Here's the var-dump: object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (12) { ["title"]=> string(26) "The Legend of Rex Slinkard" ["location"]=> string(71) "Cantor Arts Center, just off Palm Drive, at Museum Way and Lomita Drive" ["beginDate"]=> string(16) "November 9, 2011" ["beginTime"]=> string(8) "11:00 AM" ["beginDay"]=> string(9) "Wednesday" ["sponsor"]=> string(17) "/events/246/24657" ["repeatText"]=> string(68) "Ongoing every day from November 9, 2011 through February 26, 2012. " ["description"]=> string(255) "The Cantor Arts Center is the primary repository of paintings and sketches by the early ...

Comment: I've updated with an answer and just tested to make sure it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is here:

```
            <?php if ($event->Media['url'] == !null) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $event->Media['url'];?>" alt="<?php echo $event->title;?> thumbnail" />
            <?php } ?>
```

You're trying to access url as though it were an attribute, you need to access it as a child element by using `->url` instead.

```
            <?php if ($event->Media->url != null) { ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $event->Media->url;?>" alt="<?php echo $event->title;?> thumbnail" />
            <?php } ?>
```

***EDIT***: By the way, `== !null` works as you expect, but `!= null` is a bit friendlier and less confusing

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement is incorrect.  It should be:

```
if ($event->Media['url'] != null)
```

Comment: Actually this is tricker than you think `$event->Media['url'] == !null` there's a hint in the following code: `if (true == !null) { echo "true"; }` The output? `true`. The reason why is that you're checking if the value is the ***negation*** of null, which not null is equal to true. Though yes, as I mentioned != null is a bit easier to read.